# Unable to bind to a variable

Tags: apache-flex

```
            import server.valueObjects.Data;

            [Bindable] 
            public var dbl:Number;
            [Bindable]
            public var val:String;


            public function clientMonitor():void{
                var callResp:CallResponder = new CallResponder();
                callResp.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, monitorResult);
                callResp.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, monitorFault);
                callResp.token = plcServiceBean.getMonitorData();
            }

            public function monitorResult(event:ResultEvent):void{
                dbl = event.result.value as Number;
                val = dbl.toString();
                trace (dbl);
                trace(val);
            }

            protected function monitorFault(event:FaultEvent):void{
                Alert.show(event.fault.faultString, "Error while monitoring Data ");
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="contentJustify" />
    </s:layout>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <plcservicebean:PlcServiceBean id = "plcServiceBean" 
                                       showBusyCursor="true" 
                                       fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <mx:Form height="103">
        <mx:FormItem label="View" x="2" y="11">
            <s:TextInput id = "view1"
                         text="{val}"/>
        </mx:FormItem>
    </mx:Form>
</s:Panel>
```

Here the method clientMonitor() is called on creationcomplete() from the main application.

I am not able to bind the Bindable variable dbl to my textInput. Using the debugger, I am able to see that the result is assigned successfully to variable dbl, but it is not able to bind it to the text of view1. I see a NaN displayed in the text of view1.

-H

Comment: But you're shoving a number where a string goes and asking it to bind...

Comment: What does `trace(event.result.value);` print in `monitorResult()`

Comment: Yes,

trace(event.result.value) prints the desired 100.11

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to bind a Number to a String.  Try making the types the same and see if that has an effect.

Comment: Your code segment in the comment is fairly useless to parse.  

That said, you don't appear to have a result handler set on your PlcServiceBean class.  Should you?  Are you sure that the monitorResult is being fired?

Comment: Could it be because I am using an event handler for a web service method, executed upon creationComplete(), that I am not able to bind the variable when the method finishes execution?

Comment: I have modified the code in the question to incorporate changes suggested.It also reflects my difficult to parse comment above. I am calling the clientMonitor() upon creation complete and upon getting the result monitorResult() is invoked. I am sure that the monitorResult() is being fired, because I can see the trace(dbl) and trace(val) prints the desired result. Variable val fails to bind to the text="{val}". The text remains blank.

Comment: Using an event handler to trigger a web service call should have no effect on binding.  
The code in your original sample is not calling anything upon creationComplete.

Comment: I have not posted my main Application. In my main Application, I have a creationComplete which calls the clientMonitor().